# Representing set-theoretical notions in terms of lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, set, pattern-matching

I'm trying to define a new type in Haskell (i.e. sets) and to operate with it in terms of functions that input and output unordered lists without duplicates.

Am I on the right path over here? Any suggestion is welcomed, even the most minor quibble. I'd want my code to be as elegant as possible.

```
-- generalized membership

type Set a = [a]

member :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
member x []                 = False
member x (y:ys) | x == y    = True
                | otherwise = member x ys                

-- elimination of duplicates

noReps :: Set Integer -> Set Integer
noReps []                   = []
noReps (x:xs) | member x xs = noReps xs
              | otherwise   = x : noReps xs

inclusion :: Set Integer -> Set Integer -> Bool
inclusion x y = length [i | i <- x, not (member i y)] == 0

identical :: Set Integer -> Set Integer -> Bool 
identical x y = inclusion x y && inclusion y x

-- membership for sets of sets

setmember :: Set Integer -> Set (Set Integer) -> Bool
setmember [] _                      = True
setmember _ []                      = False
setmember x (y:ys)  | identical x y = True 
                    | otherwise     = setmember x ys   

addsets :: Set Integer -> Set (Set Integer) -> Set (Set Integer)
addsets x y | setmember x y = y
            | otherwise = x:y

-- adding an integer to every member of a sets of sets of integers

addelem :: Integer -> Set (Set Integer) -> Set (Set Integer) 
addelem x y = [noReps (x : i) | i <- y]

-- powerset of the set {1,...,n}

powerset :: Integer -> Set (Set Integer)
powerset 1 = [[], [1]]
powerset x = powerset (x-1) ++ addelem x (powerset (x-1))
```

Comment: Haskell actually already has a `Set` type. Yours is just a synonym for lists (which are different, lists can have multiple of the same element, and have a defined order), and a lot of these functions for lists are already defined in the `Data.List` module.

Comment: This is mostly an exercise in futility, I know, I know. But the examiner asked us to define everything ourselves.

Comment: Since you're asking for general advice on your approach rather than asking a question about a specific bug or issue, I think the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site would be a better fit.

Comment: Also implementing sets with lists -- especially in Haskell -- would be quite inefficient as membership checking (one of the most used functions with sets) is linear and not constant time.

Answer (score 2):

Looks good to me (for an "exercise in futility", as you put it); one thing: None of your signatures require specializing as Integer, anything that supports equality (Eq) will work, with powerset additionally requiring a numeric value (again, not necessarily an Integer):

```hs
noReps :: Eq a => Set a -> Set a
inclusion :: Eq a => Set a -> Set a -> Bool
identical :: Eq a => Set a -> Set a -> Bool 
setmember :: Eq a => Set a -> Set (Set a) -> Bool
addsets :: Eq a => Set a -> Set (Set a) -> Set (Set a)
addelem :: Eq a => a -> Set (Set a) -> Set (Set a) 
powerset :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> Set (Set a)
```

All these signatures will work, without changing absolutely anything in the functions themselves.

(EDIT: it is usually a good idea to make your signatures as generic and polymorphic as possible - not only will allow reusing the code, but, by restricting what your functions can do with their arguments - in this case, the signature allows you ONLY applying the == operator - you reduce the risk of bugs / unintended effects).

Of course, using lists will make the code simple yet slow - for real-life code, you'd use balanced trees to represent the sets - more complex, but fast; in fact, that's how Haskell's own Set type is implemented.